# Resonance Audio Source - Unity3D Collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I added the Reasonance Audio Source to an object and wanted to generate a sound when a collision between that object and another object occurred.

The issue I am having is that OnCollisionEnter in Unity is triggered whenever the object gets within the "audio region" (a blue disk attached to the object with a certain radius). However, what I am interested is when the physical collision occurs, and not this "audio" collision.

One way to go around it is just to create a copy of that object, without the Reasonance Audio Source which follows the motion of the other object. Then you trigger collisions the object copy. But I was wondering if there is any way to differentiate these two types of collisions in Unity?

Here is an example. Red ball is the object I want to generate the sound from and that has the Reasonance Audio Source as a component. The blue region is created from that component. Whenever the blue disk touches the grey floor, a collision is generated. I would like to disable this "audio" collision and have only a collision being detected when a physical collision between the red ball and the grey floor occurs.

[image]

EDIT: Found the problem. I had been testing the PhysicsManager properties (Edit/Project Settings/Physics) and I had the "Default contact offset" set to 0.01 which by change was the same as the blue region, so I went looking for a problem in the wrong place. I now changed the contact offset to a smaller value and all is ok.

Comment: try giving screenshots or code samples of what you have tried so far if you want more specific answers.

Comment: Thanks! I have now added an image of the example to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PhysicsManager properties (Edit/Project Settings/Physics) the "Default contact offset" defines the blue region. Change the value to a smaller one to resize the contact region.

OLD ANSWER:

Without knowing your scene or code i can only speculate that you might want to turn of the audio sources collision and trigger it manually when the collision with the object occurs. Just attach a script that listens for a collision and then trigger the collision event of the audio source (or just play the sound).

Comment: Right, but how do you disable the audio collision? I could not find any distinction between an audio collision and a physical collision.

Comment: You could use a normal audio source, which has no collision. From the looks of your image, you could probably also reduce the size of the resonance audio source to make it fit the radius of the ball.

Comment: But then I would not use the reasonance audio source which has benefits over the normal audio source right? 
How can that radius be changed? Would that not affect the sound that is provided to the user if one changes that?

Feels like there should be a more elegant solution to this problem or?

Comment: What exactly are you doing when the collisions occur? Do you play the sound, change the volume? On which collision do you do that? Can you ignore collision events from the audio source and start the audio on the collision event of the object?

Comment: I want to generate a sound when the two objects physically collide. I want the specific sound to be generated from this object on collision, which should be coming from the reasonance audio source, and want to be able to manipulate this sound, like volume, etc. The audio source is a component of the object which is colliding, and Unity does not distinguish between the collision of the audio source and the collision of the physical object.

Comment: Will try your idea to put the audio source in the child object!

Comment: Found the problem. In the PhysicsManager properties (Edit/Project Settings/Physics) I had the "Default contact offset" set to 0.01 which by change was the same as the blue region, so I went looking for a problem in the wrong place. I now changed the contact offset to a smaller value and all is ok. Sorry for the stupid mistake!

Comment: @jaraujo Make this an answer and accept it, so future visitors will see at first glance what solved your problem. :)

Comment: could you change your answer then to incorporate my solution? Just say that one should check in the physicsmanager properties, etc. etc. and I put your answer as correct. Your answer at the moment does not really solve this problem.